# Removing a property from entity in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I remove a property from an entity in Jhipster and the system still looks for it when persisting to the database.

Example
I generated an entity previously with examples below then I went back to remove the paymentDate property from the entity.

```
Old
entity payment{
   name String,
   amount BigDecimal,
   paymentDate Instant
}

New
entity payment{
   name String,
   amount BigDecimal
}
```

Now when I try to save data to the payment table, it is asking me for paymentDate property and I still see it in my database. Even if I delete the table and restart the application, I still see the paymentDate property. What I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You must write a Liquibase migration to remove the column using `dropColumn` element.

https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates-by-manually-editing-the-change-log

https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/drop-column.html

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the change log files and the entities, then regenerate the jdl. That's fix my issue.

Comment: This works while you are still in dev, as soon as you are in production and have real data to keep, changelogs should be considered as immutable..